# Solve $\begin{cases} x^3+1=81(y^2+y)\\x^2+x=9(y^3+1) \end{cases}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Solve $\begin{cases} x^3+1=81(y^2+y)\\x^2+x=9(y^3+1) \end{cases}$

$\Leftrightarrow \begin{cases} (x+1)(x^2-x+1)=81y(y+1)\\ x(x+1)=9(y+1)(y^2-y+1) \end{cases}$

Then I'm stuck. I'm not seeing any patterns here. Please help.

Comment: Hint : add three times the second line to the first one.

Comment: You have asked more then $10$ such questions recently, all very similar. What is the aim of it? You could start trying it yourself without help (if it is an exam preparation).

Comment: I'm sorry I upset you Dietrich. Are you feeling better now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do
$$
x^3 + 3x^2 + 3x + 1 = 27(y^3 + 3y^2 + 3y + 1)
$$
by adding 3 times the second line to the first line, then this is just
$$
(x+1)^3 = 27(y+1)^3
$$
So if $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$, this implies $x+1 = 3(y+1)$, i.e. $x = 3y+2$. Substituting this back into the first equation gives
$$
\begin{align}
27y^3 + 54y^2 + 36y + 9 = 81y^2 + 81y &\Leftrightarrow 27y^3 - 27y^2 - 45y + 9 = 0 \\
&\Leftrightarrow 3y^3 - 3y^2 - 5y + 1 = 0 \\
&\Leftrightarrow (y+1) \left(y-\left(1 - \sqrt{2/3}\right)\right) \left(y + \left(1+\sqrt{2/3}\right)\right) = 0 \\
\end{align}
$$

So $(x,y) = (-1, -1)$ or $\left(5 - \sqrt{6}, 1 - \sqrt{2/3}\right)$ or $\left(5 + \sqrt{6}, 1 + \sqrt{2/3}\right)$.

Comment: Please don't answer questions without context and where the OP didn't show effort. It goes against the rules of this site.